# HTTP 500 error when generating Java Client Library using endpointscfg from a GAE API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, go, google-api, google-api-java-client

I tried to generate java client library using a discovery doc retrieved from my API endpoints (which is running on golang) but failed wit the following message.

```
endpointscfg.py gen_client_lib java happylaundry.rest.discovery

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/endpointscfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "//Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/endpointscfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 561, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 557, in main
    args.callback(args)
  File "/Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 458, in _GenClientLibCallback
    args.build_system)
  File "/Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 335, in _GenClientLib
    build_system, client_name)
  File "/Users/lorenz/go/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 366, in _GenClientLibFromContents
    raise ServerRequestException(error)
__main__.ServerRequestException: HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) error when communicating with URL: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/generate. Response:
```

I tried to use the same command and generated for a very simple program, and it runs without errro. From the syntax or structure of the discovery doc, i can't see anything ran wrong. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove this part from "schema" section from the discovery document, and it works.

"Order": {
   "id": "Order",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
    "addressArea": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "addressDistrict": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "addressField1": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "addressField2": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "addressField3": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "addressField4": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "amountPayable": {
     "type": "integer",
     "format": "int32"
    },
    "completed": {
     "type": "boolean"
    },
    "createdAt": {
     "type": "string",
     "format": "date-time"
    },
    "deliveryDate": {
     "type": "string",
     "format": "date-time"
    },
    "deliveryTimeslot": {
     "type": "integer",
     "format": "int32"
    },
    "id": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "pickupDate": {
     "type": "string",
     "format": "date-time"
    },
    "pickupDeliveryInstruction": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "pickupTimeslot": {
     "type": "integer",
     "format": "int32"
    },
    "referenceNumber": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
     "type": "integer",
     "format": "int32"
    },
    "－": {
     "type": "string"
    }
   }
  },